# SQL - Comparing text(combinations) on 100million table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a problem.
I have a table that has around 80-100million records in it. In that table I have a field, that has stored from 3 up to 16 different "combinations"(varchar). Combination is a 4-digit number, a colon and a char(A-E), . For example:
`'0001:A/0002:A/0005:C/9999:E'`. In this case there are 4 different combinations (they can go up to 16). This field is in every row of the table, never a null.

Now the problem: I have to go through the table, find every row, and see if they are similar.
Example rows:

```
0001:A/0002:A/0003:C/0005:A/0684:A/0699:A/0701:A/0707:A/0709:A/0710:D/0711:C/0712:A/0713:A
0001:A/0002:A/0003:C
0001:A/0002:A/0003:A/0006:C
0701:A/0709:A/0711:C/0712:A/0713:A
```

As you can see, each of these rows is  similar to the others (in some way). The thing that needs to be done here is when you send `'0001:A/0002:A/0003:C'` via program(or parameter in SQL), that it checks every row and see if they have the same "group". Now the catch here is that it has to go both ways and it has to be done "quick", and the SQL needs to compare them somehow.

So when you send `'0001:A/0002:A/0003:C/0005:A/0684:A/0699:A/0701:A/0707:A/0709:A/0710:D/0711:C/0712:A/0713:A'` it has to find all fields where there are 3-16 same combinations and return the rows. This 3-16 can be specified via parameter, but the problem is that you would need to find all possible combinations, because you can send `'0002:A:/0711:C/0713:A'`, and as you can see you can send `0002:A` as the first parameter.

But you cannot have indexing because a combination can be on any place in a string, and you can send different combinations that are not "attached" (there could be a different combination in the middle).

So, sending `'0001:A/0002:A/0003:C/0005:A/0684:A/0699:A/0701:A/0707:A/0709:A/0710:D/0711:C/0712:A/0713:A'` has to return all fields that has the same 3-16 fields
and it has to go both ways, if you send "0001:A/0002:A/0003:C" it has to find the row above + similar rows(all that contain all the parameters).

Some things/options I tried:

- Doing LIKE for all send combinations is not practical + too slow
- Giving a field full-index search isn't an option(don't know why exactly)
- One of the few things that could work would be making some "hash" type of encoding for fields, calculating it via program, and searching for all same "hashes"(Don't know how would you do that, given that the hash would generate different combinations for similar texts, maybe some hash that would be written exactly for that
- Making a new field, calculating/writing(can be done on insert) all possible combinations and checking via SQL/program if they have the same % of combinations, but I don't know how you can store 10080 combinations(in case of 16) into a "varchar" effectively, or via some hash code + knowing then which of them are familiar.

There is another catch, this table is in usage almost 24/7, doing combinations to check if they are the same in SQL is too slow because the table is too big, it can be done via program or something, but I don't have any clue on how could you store this in a new row that you would know somehow that they are the same. It is a possibility that you would calculate combinations, storing them via some hash code or something on each row insert, calculating "hash" via program, and checking the table like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ROW = "a346adsad"
```

where the parameter would be sent via program.
This script would need to be executed really fast, under 1 minute, because there could be new inserts into the table, that you would need to check.

The whole point of this would be to see if there are any similar combinations in SQL already and blocking any new combination that would be "similar" for inserting.

I have been dealing with that problem for 3 days now without any possible solution, the thing that was the closest is different type of insert/hash like, but I don't know how could that work.

Thank you in advance for any possible help, or if this is even possible!

Comment: This sounds like a perfect opportunity to normalise your table. You can then search using indexes, which'll be quicker.

Comment: The best thing to do is to redesign your database to get rid of this "multiple values in a single field" approach.  Relational databases are very good at dealing with finding matching fields, but not so good at doing substring operations, regular expressions, etc.

Comment: Why is this tagged [mysql] and [oracle]?

Comment: Also, do you mena "permutations" or do you mean "combinations"? In the mathematical sense I mean. I notice you do you use "combination" but soemwhere where "element" or "segment" might make more sense.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant all possible combinations without repeat

Comment: What I'm driving at is, *does the order matter*?  http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`it checks every row and see if they have the same "group".`

IMHO if the **group** is a basic element of your data structure, your database structure is flawed: it should have each group in its own cell to be normalized. The structure you described makes it clear that you store a composite value in the field.

I'd tear up the table into 3:

- one for the "header" information of the group sequences
- one for the groups themselves
- a connecting table between the two

Something along these lines:

```
CREATE TABLE GRP_SEQUENCE_HEADER (
    ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    DESCRIPTION TEXT
  );


CREATE TABLE GRP (
    ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    GROUP_TXT CHAR(6)
  );

CREATE TABLE GRP_GRP_SEQUENCE_HEADER (
    GROUP_ID BIGINT, 
    GROUP_SEQUENCE_HEADER_ID BIGINT,
    GROUP_SEQUENCE_HEADER_ORDER INT, /* For storing the order in the sequence */
    PRIMARY KEY(GROUP_ID, GROUP_SEQUENCE_HEADER_ID)
  );
```

(of course, add the foreign keys, and most importantly the indexes necessary)

Then you only have to break up the input into groups, and execute a simple query on a properly indexed table.

Also, you would probably save on the disk space too by not storing duplicates...

A sample query for finding the "similar" sequences' IDs:

```
SELECT ggsh.GROUP_SEQUENCE_HEADER_ID,COUNT(1)
FROM GRP_GRP_SEQUENCE_HEADER ggsh  
JOIN GRP g ON ggsh.GROUP_ID=g.GROUP_ID
WHERE g.GROUP_TXT IN (<groups to check for from the sequence>)
GROUP BY gsh.ID
HAVING COUNT(1) BETWEEN 3 AND 16 --lower and upper boundaries
```

This returns all the header IDs that the current sequence is similar to.

**EDIT**
Rethinking it a bit more, you could even break up the group into the two parts, but as I seem to understand, you always have full groups to deal with, so it doesn't seem to be necessary.

**EDIT2** Maybe if you want to speed the process up even more, I'd recommend to translate the sequences using bijection into numeric data. For example, evaluate the first 4 numbers to be an integer, shift it by 4 bits to the left (multiply by 16, but quicker), and add the hex value of the character in the last place.

Examples:

```
0001/A --> 1 as integer, A is 10, so 1*16+10 =26
...
0002/B --> 2 as integer, B is 11, so 2*16+11 =43
...
0343/D --> 343 as integer, D is 13, so 343*16+13 =5501
...
9999/E --> 9999 as integer, E is 14, so 9999*16+14 =159998 (max value, if I understood correctly)
```

Numerical values are handled more efficiently by the DB, so this should result in an even better performance - of course with the new structure.

Comment: Thank you for fast response! But what do you mean with "header" information?

Comment: Well, the header information would be every field other than the groups, plus an ID field to be able to reference from the group table. But I think I'll add some DDL like info to my answer

Comment: I just don't understand something. If I have HEADER(1,2,3,...) and then GRP(0001:A, 0001:B -> 9999:E), how can I store multiple foreign keys into SEQ, because I need to have like SEQ(1, FOREIGN(HEADER_ID), FOREIGN(GRP_ID)) but rows are looking on at least 3 different rows in GRP_ID, like SEQ(1, 2, (1,20, 40000,...)) and it can look then on 16 different rows in GRP?

Comment: @Tomek: you will have multiple rows in SEQ for one header. I updated my answer to show a sample query on such the structure to find all similar entries. I also added a remark on translating the string values into numerical values, that should speed the process  up significantly.

Comment: I just want to say I am very thankful for your help. I just though about having multiple rows, didn't know how I couldn't think about that earlier, and thanks for everything again, I will try this now!

Answer (score 2):

So basically you want to execute a complex string manipulation on *80-100 million rows* in less than a minute!  Ha, ha, good one!

Oh wait, you're serious.

You cannot hope to do these searches on the fly.  Read Joel Spolsky's piece on getting [Back to Basics](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) to understand why.

What you need to do is hive off those 80-100 million strings into their own table, broken up into those discrete tokens i.e. `'0001:A/0002:A/0003:C'` is broken up into three records (perhaps of two columns - you're a bit a vague about the relationship between the numeric and alphabetic components of th etokens).  Those records can be indexed.

Then it is simply a matter of tokenizing the search strings and doing a select joining the search tokens to the new table.  Not sure how well it will perform: that rather depends on how many distinct tokens you have.

Comment: Yes I kinda figured out that this is kinda impossible to do, I was just hoping there could be an easy fix with some kind of value calculated based on combinations. Thanks for resposne!

Answer (score 0):

As people have commented you would benefit immensely from normalizing your data, but can you not cheat and create a temp table with the key and exploding out your column on the "/", so you go from

```
KEY | "0001:A/0002:A/0003:A/0006:C"
KEY1| "0001:A/0002:A/0003:A"
```

to

```
KEY | 0001:A
KEY | 0002:A
KEY | 0003:A
KEY | 0006:C
KEY1| 0001:A
KEY1| 0002:A
KEY1| 0003:A
```

Which would allow you to develop a query something like the following (not tested):

```
SELECT
    t1.key
    , t2.key
    , COUNT(t1.*)
FROM
    temp_table t1
    , temp_table t2
    , ( SELECT t3.key, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM temp_table t3 GROUP BY t3.key) t4
WHERE
    t1.combination IN ( 
        SELECT 
            t5.combination 
        FROM 
            temp_table t5 
        WHERE 
            t5.key = t2.key)
    AND t1.key <> t2.key
HAVING
    COUNT(t1.*) = t4.cnt
```

So return the two keys where key1 is a proper subset of key?

Comment: Why create a temporary table (and by implication continually re-populate it)?  Why not a permanent table, which is what the rest of us are suggesting?

Comment: Ah I had mistaken it to be a one time process.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can recommend to build special "index".
It will be quite big but you will achieve superspeedy results.

Let's consider this task as searching a set of symbols.
There are design conditions.
The symbols are made by pattern "NNNN:X", where NNNN is number [0001-9999] and X is letter [A-E].
So we have 5 * 9999 = 49995 symbols in alphabet.
Maximum length of words with this alphabet is 16.

We can build for each word set of combinations of its symbols.
For example, the word "abcd" will have next combinations:

```
abcd
abc
ab
a
abd
acd
ac
ad
bcd
bc
b
bd
cd
с
d
```

As symbols are sorted in words we have only 2^N-1 combinations (15 for 4 symbols).
For 16-symbols word there are 2^16 - 1 = 65535 combinations.

So we make for an additional index-organized table like this one

```
create table spec_ndx(combination varchar2(100), original_value varchar2(100))
```

Performance will be excellent with price of overhead - in the worst case for each record in the original table there will be 65535 "index" records.
So for 100-million table we will get 6-trillion table.
But if we have short values size of "special index" reduces drastically.